# Angular *ngIf Directive Does Not Trigger Change Detection When Bound to a Function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button that I would like to show only if something is dirty and requires a save.  I have the following within my HTML

```
<mat-action-row>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="IsDirty(segmentGroup)"
         (click)="Save(segmentGroup)">Save</button>
</mat-action-row>
```

Here is the IsDirty Method in the TS

```
IsDirty(segmentGroup: SegmentGroup) {
    // Segment Group Dirty
    if (segmentGroup.isDirty)
      return true;

    segmentGroup.segmentDefinitions.forEach(segmentDefinition => {
      if (segmentDefinition.isDirty || segmentDefinition.startTimeLineDefinition.isDirty || segmentDefinition.endTimeLineDefinition.isDirty)
        return true;
    });

    return false;
  }
```

I need to check 3 levels of the object for an is dirty field, ie itself, a child object that is within an array, and a child object of the child within the array.

The issue i have is, the *ngIf method is called when the button is rendered and only when the button is rendered.  Its not bound to a property therefore change detection doesnt trigger anything.  So if I update IsDirty on any of the 3 levels the button never shows.

Is there a way to force the re-render or execution of the ngIf when either a property is changed or on a (change) event on the input?

Comment: You can force a change detection cycle but there is probably a better way. Are you using reactive forms?

Comment: the change detection cycle wont catch that button because nothing has changed as it its not bound to anything

Comment: Have you tried it? I think it might force the template to refresh and therefore re-evaluate the `ngIf`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you answered your own question, using a function for the `*ngIf` directive will only be evaluated when the element is connected to the DOM and subsequent change detection cycles triggered by other means.

You could programmatically force change detection per the comment above to force the function call however, I believe the more appropriate implementation is as you pointed out, to bind the directive to a local class variable.

- Calling functions directly from template markup is frowned upon for
  performance reasons

---

```
isDirty = false

<button *ngIf="isDirty">

isDirty = true
```

The above will trigger change detection because false is no longer equal to true, hence the term `"change detection"`.

---

```
*ngIf="isDirty()"
```

This will never trigger change detection without some other means because `function` is always equal to `function` and it never changes... thus no change to trigger `"change detection"`

---

Set a boolean value to a local variable and bind that to the `*ngIf` directive, then find some other means to trigger your `isDirty` function to set that boolean value... on form change or input change is the typical implementation to calling a function like this.

Comment: The issue with this is the object where the save button would show is a list.  So there would be N number of local variables created to track each object in that list

Comment: The details on triggering the `isDirty` function were to outline the most typical approach, you will need to figure out the implementation that best suits your domain for calling the function. The details on setting a boolean variable and binding it to the directive still apply and answer the question, as, your function is responsible for classifying the N number of variables and distilling them down to one boolean that is bound to the directive.